# Can I cast a pointer to char?

Tags: c, casting

Can I cast `void*` to `char[]`, or is this illegal? I just want to take a look at the bits. I'm aware of `intptr_t`, but I would rather not use a typedef that may or may not exist on a given platform.

Comment: If you want to look at the bits, then just printf with %p.

Comment: @stark No, I actually want to interact with the bits. I want to do bitwise operations on them. I want to use them in some meaningful way. I'm aware of `%p`, but I want to specifically know if I can cast a `void*` to a `char[]`.

Comment: char is a poor choice, since it may be signed.  To interact with the bits, use `unsigned char *`.

Comment: Are you interested in the bits of the pointer, or of the data that the pointer points to?

Comment: If you have `void *p`, you can see its bits using `printf("%p\n", p)`, and you can see the bits that it points to using `printf("%hhx\n", *(unsigned char *)p)`.  And if you want to "interact" with thost bits... well, that depends. :-)

Comment: If you want to see the bytes of the pointer, you can cast `&ptr` to `char *`, then index that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I cast a pointer to char?

Yes, but that is only useful in esoteric circumstances, such as checking the low bits to see the alignment.

> Can I cast void* to char[], or is this illegal?

Casting to `char []` violates the constraint for the cast operator in C 2018 6.5.4 2:

> Unless the type name specifies a void type, the type name shall specify atomic, qualified, or unqualified scalar type, and the operand shall have scalar type.

`char []` is not any of those scalar types.

You can cast to `char *`, but that will not give you the bytes of the pointer; it will give you the pointer as a pointer to `char`.

> I'm aware of intptr_t, but I would rather not use a typedef that may or may not exist on a given platform.

`uintptr_t` is generally preferable to `intptr_t`, to avoid complications caused by the sign. There are few C implementations in which it would not exist.

However, there could be some. For that, you can convert not the pointer, but the **address** of the pointer to `unsigned char *`. That will give you a new pointer to the bytes of the pointer, and then you can use that to examine those bytes. Again, prefer the unsigned type, `unsigned char *`, to avoid complications from signedness.

Comment: Well, "a pointer to `char *`" is technically `char **`. It's hard to say whether OP is trying to type pun the pointer against an array of bytes, such as in `union { void *ptr; char unsigned byte[sizeof (void *)]; }`. I'm sure you're aware of this, just thought to mention it because this is _the other way_ OP might be interested in, without a complex-seeming cast such as `(char *) &(void *){0}`.